# Understanding software business model

Tags: work-experience, projects

Why do companies give more importance to shareholders than employees?

Aren't employees more important than shareholders?

Employees work very hard to complete the tasks and generate the product, but a shareholder puts money in equities or others in that company, sits idle and gets money without any work.

I see that companies fire employees to earn profits but won't stop giving money to shareholders.

Facebook, which is a billion dollars company, removed employees, so where do those billion of dollars go? Can't it give at least 8k dollars per month to an employee from those billions of dollars?

Comment: How did the shareholders get the money to invest in the stock in the first place if not for work?  Businesses exist to do and/or make stuff which, if people freely want to, they pay for.  They are not "employers" nor charities. Milton Friedman said it better.

Answer (score 4):

Companies *are* the shareholders. Every shareholder owns a small part of the company. All shareholders together own the whole company. To the shareholders, shareholders are more important than employees. Therefore to the company, shareholders are worth more than employees.

Now it is very commonly the case that a company trying to exploit its employees will suffer in the long term, make less profit, and therefore make shareholders suffer in the long term. One CEO I knew said “look after your customers, and look after your employees, and the share price will look after itself”.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question - we must first understand who a Shareholder is:

They are someone who has typically invested money into the business. Could be as small as a single Dollar, could be as large as several billion dollars.

There are other situations where a shareholder may not have invested actual Cash in the company, but we'll leave those to one side, for now.

So, why would someone be a shareholder? The answer is that it typically gives a better return on their investment than a Bank, but with greater risk.

If I take say, $100,000 and I stick it in a Bank - assuming a normal economic situation, I can reasonably expect 1-2% growth PA, it's low risk - but also low reward.

Whereas I can stick my $100,000 as an investment into a Business and look to get between 10-20% return on my investment (depending on whether the business is doing well etc.)

How is that return realized? There's two key ways - the first is in the abstract increase in value - if my $100,000 buys 10% of a company, and that company grows in value from $1 Million to $3 Million, my 10% investment now has a value of $300,000 - however, this is all on Paper. As with the current Crypto collapse, paper gains can very quickly become paper losses.

The other method is Dividends - where the company pays the shareholder an agreed percentage per share of the company total value, in return for them keeping their investment.

Why is this important?

Well - say I invest in a Company, at $100,000, for my 10% stake, the company uses that investment to buy some new equipment. Now 6 months later, I'm not happy with the direction the company is heading and I decide to withdraw my investment.

Assuming no net growth, the company now has to either find another investor to buy the shares off of me, or the company has to buy them back - and find $100,000 to buy me out.

This puts the business interest in keeping shareholders happy in perspective. It is their Cash investment that allows them to purchase big ticket items without getting a loan from a bank and paying interest and if they don't keep their shareholders happy, the shareholders withdraw their investment and the company suddenly has to find cash. It could be selling equipment, laying off workers etc.

Now - compare this to when an Employee leaves - they get paid out their leave balance and that's about it.

To answer your question:

"I see that companies fire employees to earn profits but won't stop giving money to shareholders.

Facebook, which is a billion dollars company, removed employees, so where do those billion of dollars go? Can't it give at least 8k dollars per month to an employee from those billions of dollars?"

That Billion dollar valuation is on paper, it's tied up with physical assets (Buildings, Data Centres, infrastructure etc.)

In a choice between pissing off the people who could withdraw their investment causing even more financial hardship (and in extreme cases bankruptcy) vs firing some under-performing employees (whose departure isn't as catastrophic as investors leaving) - that is why it can't 'give at least 8k dollars per month to an employee.'

Answer (score 1):

> Why do companies give more importance to shareholders than employees?

Some reasons could be:

1. **Shareholders** elect members of the **board of directors**.
   In turn, the board of directors decide who will be the
   CEO of the company.

   **Employees** do not elect the CEO, and only take orders from the CEO.

   **So, the shareholders have more influences to the CEO than normal employees.**

   Essentially, this is the chain of command in a capitalistic economy.
2. The CEO and other executives of the company may also be the big
   shareholders. They could own lots of shares through sign-on bonus or
   other programs.
3. For startups or small companies, shareholders are the ones who take
   lots of financial risks to invest into these startups. Most startups fail while only a very small number of startups succeed.

---

> "Facebook, which is a billion dollars company, removed employees, so where do those billion of dollars go? Can't it give at least 8k dollars per month to an employee from those billions of dollars?".

That is not how capitalism works. If a company loses profit, they will let employees go to cut costs and save money. However, if a company makes lots of profit, they will hire more workers to expand their business.

Answer (score 1):

Another part is that it is easier to find employees than to find investors, especially investors who can properly help management. Good investors are not passive, they interact with the management and offer different viewpoints that help.

When looking around at how companies get started, investors are hard to find. Most companies starting up don't have enough money. Most people starting a company can't find investors and the people start the company with their own savings. Thus, if an investor shows up, the people starting the company will give attention. Just look at the interest in being on those "shark tank" type programs.

On the other side are companies that have "made it big". If Facebook management does not take care of the investors, they will vote to remove the management. That gives powerful incentive to take care of the investors. (This is why investors expressing concern about current directions at Facebook are noted.)